# get field as string in join table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table structure

Table1

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | user_id |
+-----+---------+
| 1   | 123     |
| 2   | 456     |
+-----+---------+
```

Table2

```
+-----+----------+------+------+
| id  | user_id  | data | name |
+-----+----------+------+------+
| 1   | 123      | abc  | Tom  |
| 2   | 123      | xyz  | Jon  |
| 3   | 456      | pqr  | Johny|
+-----+----------+------+------+
```

I want to list count of data in **Table2** for each user along with the **data** column joined as a string next to count column in the resultant table.

My SQL query is like

```
SELECT t1.user_id, count(t2.id) as c
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
```

This lists data as

```
+---------+------+
| user_id | c    |
+---------+------+
| 123     | 2    |
| 456     | 1    |
+---------+------+
```

But I want data like

```
+---------+------+-------------+
| user_id | c    | datas       |
+---------+------+-------------+
| 123     | 2    | abc, xyz    |
| 456     | 1    | pqr         |
+---------+------+-------------+
```

**How could I select the data joined by comma?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT t1.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.data SEPARATOR ','),count(t2.id) as c
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
group by t1.user_id
```

Comment: You want to add `SEPARATOR ', '`.

Answer (score 0):

I think following idea will match you.

```
SELECT  user_id 
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(datas AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM Table2 
         WHERE user_id = t.user_id 
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM Table2 t
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Looks more like an MS SQL Server query. (MySQL doesn't support this syntax.)